# Linking two separate networks

Tags: networking, lan

I have a large open mesh network and the client wants to use it for some Mitel WiFi phones. The Mitel is currently on a separate network. The Mitel engineer has connected to our switch but his Mitel system is a completely different subnet and cannot be changed. The Mitel subnet is 10.16.10.2 whereas my WiFi network is 192.168.10.x, no surprise he cannot ping the Mitel from WiFi!

Is there a way I can link the 2 networks to enable the open mesh WiFi to communicate to the Mitel?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of router do you have? Or does the Mitel engineer provide their own router?

Comment: I am using an open mesh (now Datto) D200 router but there is a router per network, the other is Cisco